# Replacement of space to + in python

Tags: python

I have written some code in python and I got the problem that when I have for example a sentence "This is my very first python program", after using the `split` function I get a result like this:

```
['this', 'is', 'my', 'very', 'first', 'python', 'program']
['this', 'is', 'my', 'very', 'first', 'python program']
['this', 'is', 'my', 'very', 'first python program']
['this', 'is', 'my', 'very first python program']
['this', 'is', 'my very first python program']
['this', 'is my very first python program']
['this is my very first python program']
```

Now I want to pass each word separated with + signs into a url.

I would like to use a for each loop but my problem is that it should automatically replace it as I stated above.

For example, the result of `"python program"` should be `"python+program"`.

So can anyone tell me how to solve this problem in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
my_string = "this is my very first python program"
n = len(my_string.split(' '))
for i in range(n):
    my_string_split = [x.replace (" ", "+") for x in my_string.split(' ', n-i-1)]
    print my_string_split
```

Comment: Thank you I know that one but the thing is for example I have split in to 3 words like this, is my, very first python program and when I called it in a loop and send the each word to a url then for 2 and 3rd word I need to add + instead of spaces automatically

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use the right tool. What you need is to urlencode the text parameter, so you will need to use `urllib.urlencode` function.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
>>> a = "this is my first Python program"
>>> "+".join(a.split())
'this+is+my+first+Python+program'
```